# Apache2 + RewriteMap + Python -- when returning 'NULL', apache hangs

Tags: python, apache2, url-rewriting, apache

[SOLVED: See solution below.]

I'm having a problem writing a `RewriteMap` program (using Python).  I have a `RewriteMap` directive pointing to a Python script which determines if the requested URL needs to be redirected elsewhere.

When the script outputs a string terminated by a linebreak, Apache redirects accordingly.  However, when the script outputs `NULL` (with no linebreak), Apache hangs and subsequent HTTP requests are effectively ignored.

The error log shows no errors.  The rewrite log only shows a `pass through` followed by a `redirect` when successful, then only `pass through` when `NULL` is returned by the script.  Subsequent requests also only show `pass through`.

Additionally, replacing `stdout` with `os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)` to set buffer length to zero did not help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

#### /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
[...]
RewriteLock /tmp/apache_rewrite.lock
```

#### /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  [...]
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteLogLevel 1
  RewriteLog /var/www/logs/rewrite.log
  RewriteMap remap prg:/var/www/remap.py
  [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

#### /var/www/webroot/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*_.*) /${remap:$1} [R=301]
```

#### /var/www/remap.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

def getRedirect(str):
  new_url = None
  # if url needs to be redirected, put this value in new_url
  # otherwise new_url remains None
  return new_url

while True:
  request = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
  response = getRedirect(request)
  if response:
    sys.stdout.write(response + '\n')
  else:
    sys.stdout.write('NULL')
  sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: The best solution I've come up with thus far is to have the RewriteMap script return the new url or '__NULL__\n' and store this value in a ENV variable. Then, check the ENV variable for !__NULL__ and redirect. See solution below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to return a single newline, not 'NULL'.

Apache waits for a newline to know when the URL to be rewrite to ends. If your script sends no newline, Apache waits forever.

So just change `return ('NULL')` to `return ('NULL\n')`, this will then redirect to /. If you don't want this to happen, have the program to return the URL you want when there's no match in the map.

If you want not to redirect when there's no match I would:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond (${remap:$1}) !NULL
RewriteRule (.*_.*) /%1 [R=301]
```

Use a match in the RewriteCond (this would work with *NULL* as well, of course). But given your problem, this looks like the proper solution.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. I tried this and it redirects to /. In the Apache documentation, it states: '[The rewrite map program] then has to give back the looked-up value as a newline-terminated string on stdout or the four-character string ``NULL'' if it fails (i.e., there is no corresponding value for the given key).'
Source: [http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap]

Comment: Bah, I don't remember reading that ever. I've always returned an URL.
Have you tested newline terminating the string NULL?

Comment: Yes.  I've tried that and it redirects to /.  I've set it up now to return '_NULL_\n' and have RewriteCond ${remap:$1} !^_NULL_ before it.  When _NULL_ is returned, the program runs once.  However, when the program returns a value, it runs twice.  At least, this works.  I need to find a better solution though.

Comment: "... the map MapName is consulted and the key LookupKey is looked-up. If the key is found, the map-function construct is substituted by SubstValue. If the key is not found then it is substituted by DefaultValue or by the empty string if no DefaultValue was specified."

From there it looks like that NULL\n is doing the expected, this is getting replaced by the empty string.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#InternalBackRefs
This section specifies that the pattern (!NULL) not the test string (${remap:$1}) are backreferenced with %N.  Therefore, this solution will redirect to NULL or /.  I'm trying to think of combinations of RewriteCond and RewriteRules to give me the proper backreference so I can query to script at most once per request.  Again, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution I've come up with thus far is to have the RewriteMap script return the new url or `'__NULL__\n'` if no redirect is desired and store this value in a ENV variable. Then, check the ENV variable for `!__NULL__` and redirect.  See `.htaccess` file below.

Also, if anyone is planning on doing something similar to this, inside of the Python script I wrapped a fair amount of it in try/except blocks to prevent the script from dying (in my case, due to failed file/database reads) and subsequent queries being ignored.

#### /var/www/webroot/.htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ - [E=REMAP_RESULT:${remap:$1},NS]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{ENV:REMAP_RESULT} !^__NULL__$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /%{ENV:REMAP_RESULT} [R=301,L]
```

#### /var/www/remap.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

def getRedirect(str):
  try:  # to prevent the script from dying on any errors
    new_url = str
    # if url needs to be redirected, put this value in new_url
    # otherwise new_url remains None
    if new_url == str: new_url = '__NULL__'
    return new_url
  except:
    return '__NULL__'

while True:
  request = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
  response = getRedirect(request)
  sys.stdout.write(response + '\n')
  sys.stdout.flush()
```

Vinko, you definitely helped me figure this one out.  If I had more experience with `stackoverflow`, you would have received `^` from me.  Thank you.

I hope this post helps someone dealing with a similar problem in the future.

Cheers,
Andrew